# How to create a Terminal / Console like layout in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

How to create a terminal or console like layout in android studio like the Termux android app has as shown in the image above[image: white text on the black background]

I downloaded the termux app project prom github but didn't understand anything there

Answer (score 1):

Create a recyclerview that alternates EditText and TextViews.  The EditTexts will obviously be your input, and the TextViews will be output.  Then just style as needed.